# Extract Azure Estimate detials via API or JSON

Tags: json, export

I want to read the contents of an Azure estimate shared by someone via code. This is to import the data to a database.

In AWS' calculator there is an option to export to as JSON :

[image]

But in Azure export, it's only for XLSX and the share link is JavaScript based from which I cannot extract if I were to use BeautifulSoup. So how do I extract the estimate data via an API and not resort to using something like Pupeteer ?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Estimator Share link will be of the form https://azure.com/e/<long-hash>

Apparently you can get it from their API v2 JSON link :

https://azure.microsoft.com/api/v2/calculator/shared-estimates/<another-long-hash> which we'll have to extract from the first link.